# How to Add Extensions to Respective File Types - Edited & Updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, vbscript

There are two types of files; TIF, & TXT stored in two different (Windows Server 2008 and a Networked Attached Storage)  servers, shares, and folders without any extensions. **Files will be copied over to another storage area**. Approximately 92 million files. Any of the two different file types could be in any of the folders. Examples given below:

ServerName\ShareName\FolderName\FileName

1. \app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch037\1767\144
2. \app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch037\1767\146

SQL server database has a view, which has columns for the file type and UNC for each respective file in addition to other columns that are needed for the reports. Using a case statement, I am able to add the extensions to UNC path as shown in the two examples below:

Examples of UNC with extensions added using a case statement

```
`( `case when filetype = 'PAG' THEN cabinet.dbo.Imnet2UNC(imnet) + '.TIF' when filetype = 'CLD' THEN cabinet.dbo.Imnet2UNC(imnet) + '.TXT' END )`
```

1. \app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch037\1767\144.TXT
2. \app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch037\1767\146.TIF

Now I want to be able to add extensions to these files so that when users click on the UNC path in the reports they are able to automatically open the file instead of selecting an application to open it.

What are the different and/or best way to accomplish this task? Can we write some sort of a script, which basically loops through the records in the sql server view, identify the file type and finally rename the files by adding the appropriate extensions.

I look forward to your help in this regard.

Thanks!

P.S. This is my first time ever posting a question on a technical forum. Thanks everyone for guiding me on how to post questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You would just read the DB one row at the time and apply the extension to the file, assuming you have permissions?

Comment: I do have permissions. We have 92 million records, therefore, 92 million files. We cannot write some sort of a script to automate this?

Comment: If you have that many images, yes I would suggest you write a script.

Comment: I have never done anything like this before, therefore, I do not know where to start and what sort of a script is needed. Could you please guide me on how to proceed.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information for anybody to help you, e.g. what does your DB table look like. If you haven't tried anything like this before, I would strongly suggest you get some professional help with this, rather than messing up all the files .. can be an expensive adventure.

Comment: "\\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch037\1767\144.TIF" and "\\app_hpf\fcfs_data\HPF01\Arch037\1767\146.TXT" are two examples of UNC from table. I added the extensions in the table using a case statement given below: case 
 when filename = 'PAG' THEN cabinet.dbo.Imnet2UNC(imnet) + '.TIF'
 when filename = 'CLD' THEN cabinet.dbo.Imnet2UNC(imnet) + '.TXT'
 END,

Comment: As you can see a particular folder can have different file types but these files are not stored with any extensions.

Comment: Nobody can help you since you haven't really provided any useful information. If you want to add something, edit the question. Do not post stuff into comments. I would recommend you getting someone more experienced in your company to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is given below:

```
DECLARE @UNC AS varchar(255), @Filetype AS varchar(255), @CMD AS VARCHAR(255)


declare @HPF_Test as cursor;

SET @HPF_Test = CURSOR FOR


    select UNC, Filetype
    from HPF_Test;


OPEN @HPF_Test;
    Fetch NEXT from @HPF_Test into @UNC, @Filetype;
    While @@fetch_status=0
        begin 
            SELECT @CMD = 'REN ' + @UNC + ' '
 + RIGHT(@UNC, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@UNC)) - 1)
 + case when @Filetype = 'TIF' THEN '.TIF' when @Filetype = 'TXT' THEN '.TXT' when @Filetype = 'XML' THEN '.XML' END 
 FROM HPF_Test 
           exec master..xp_cmdshell @CMD
            Fetch next from @HPF_Test into @UNC, @Filetype
        end

close @HPF_Test;
deallocate @HPF_Test;
```

Comment: UNC = cabinet.dbo.Imnet2UNC(imnet)